# creating android application using http request with php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, httprequest, json

I have a simple android application in which I'm using http request and php mysql 
but the problem that the LogCat  displays is that there is an error with the path of the php file.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ??

## LogCat

```
10-15 16:42:03.380: I/dalvikvm(1596): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 16:42:03.530: I/dalvikvm(1596): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 16:42:03.860: D/gralloc_goldfish(1596): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-15 16:42:03.880: I/dalvikvm(1596): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 16:42:03.890: I/dalvikvm(1596): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 16:42:08.550: E/Error befor http(1596): Error before the http request
10-15 16:42:08.890: E/Student Data(1596): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
10-15 16:42:08.890: E/Student Data(1596): <html><head>
10-15 16:42:08.890: E/Student Data(1596): <title>404 Not Found</title>
10-15 16:42:08.890: E/Student Data(1596): </head><body>
10-15 16:42:08.890: E/Student Data(1596): <h1>Not Found</h1>
10-15 16:42:08.890: E/Student Data(1596): <p>The requested URL /studentservice/StudentService/getStudentByID.php was not found on this server.</p>
10-15 16:42:08.890: E/Student Data(1596): </body></html>
10-15 16:42:08.940: I/dalvikvm(1596): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 16:42:08.960: I/dalvikvm(1596): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 16:42:09.440: I/dalvikvm(1596): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 16:42:09.450: I/dalvikvm(1596): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

## HttpManager

```
package com.lebdev.fitguide.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.util.Log;

public class HttpManager {

    private InputStream inputStream;
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private HttpResponse httpResponse;
    private HttpPost httpPost;
    private HttpEntity httpEntity;
    private StringBuilder result;

    public HttpManager() {

        this.inputStream = null;
        this.httpClient = null;
        this.httpResponse = null;
        this.httpPost = null;
        this.httpEntity = null;
        this.result = null;

    }

    public String getResponseFromURL(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try {

            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            result = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                result.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            return result.toString();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Bufferring Error, ", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

## JsonObjectMapper

```
package com.lebdev.fitguide.om;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

import com.lebdev.fitguide.businessModel.Student;

public class JsonObjectMapper {

    public static Student jsonToStudent(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        Student std = null;

        try {

            std = new Student(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                    .getJSONObject(0).getString("Name"),
                    Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                            .getJSONObject(0).getString("Index")),
                    Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                            .getJSONObject(0).getString("ID")));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error Json Converter", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return std;
    }

    public static List<Student> jsonToStudentList(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        List<Student> stdList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student").length(); i++) {

                stdList.add(new Student(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                        .getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"), Integer
                        .parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                                .getJSONObject(i).getString("Index")), Integer
                        .parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                                .getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"))));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("Error Json Converter", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return stdList;
    }
}
```

## SecondaryActivity

```
package com.lebdev.fitguide.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.lebdev.fitguide.businessModel.Student;
import com.lebdev.fitguide.controller.HttpManager;
import com.lebdev.fitguide.controller.JSONParser;
import com.lebdev.fitguide.om.JsonObjectMapper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondaryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", "2"));

        Log.e("Error befor http", "Error before the http request");

        /*
        JSONObject jsonObj = JSONParser
                .parseJSONFromString(new HttpManager()
                        .getResponseFromURL(
                                "http://10.0.2.2/studentservice/StudentService/getStudentByID.php",
                                params));

        Log.e("Error after http", "Error after the http request");

        Student std = JsonObjectMapper.jsonToStudent(jsonObj);

        Log.e("STUDENT DATA", "ID:" + std.getID() +     "Name:" + std.getName());

        */

         HttpManager httpManager = new HttpManager();
        String result = httpManager.getResponseFromURL("http://10.0.2.2/studentservice/StudentService/getStudentByID.php",
                params);
        Log.e("Student Data", result);

/*
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            TextView lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSentMessage);
            Student student = bundle.getParcelable("Student");

            lblMessage.setText("I 've recieved a student with a name "
                    + student.getName() + " and has a Subject "
                    + student.getSubjects().get(0).getName() + " with a grade "
                    + student.getSubjects().get(0).getGrade());
        }
*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondary, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## getStudentByID.PHP

```
<?php
require_once '../ConnectionManager.php';

$response = array();
$db = connectionManager::getInstance();

if(isset($_POST["sid"]))
{
 $id = $_POST["sid"];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE ID = $id");

 if(!empty($result))
 {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0)
    {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

     $student = array();
     $student["ID"] = $row["ID"];
     $student["Index"] = $row["Index"];
     $student["Name"] = $row["Name"];

    $response ["success"] = 1;
    $response["student"] = array();

    array_push($response["student"], $student);
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
     $response["success"] = 0;
     $response["message"] = "No Student found with this ID!!";
     echo json_encode($response);
    }
 }
 else
 {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Student found with this ID!!";
    echo json_encode($response);
 }

}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required feild(s) is missing!!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: Looks like it's just a 404 not found... can you hit it manually from a browser?

Comment: Did you read the stacktrace in your first chunk of sample text? The URL you're hitting from Android doesn't exist on the server, producing a 404-not found error message.

Comment: i tried on the browser from my pc and it work fine just i changed the 10.0.2.2 to 127.0.0.1 but on the emulator it give me this error described before

Answer (score 4):

404 means that the requested page was not found. So I am guessing that if you request the same URL on a web browser then you would get the same error.

I.e.

```
http://10.0.2.2/studentservice/StudentService/getStudentByID.php
```

on your PC browser should also yield a 404 error. Are you sure that the URL is correct? maybe you have one studenservice too many?

Comment: @LebDev are you on the same network? If your mobile is on 3G then you wont have access to the 10.0.0.2 address. The phone and the PC need to be on the same network. If possible, you might want to try it from another PC on the same network and see if you get the same error there.
Otherwise the next steps are

1. use GET requests (which is what you are using if you use the browser without a FORM)

2. run wireshark on the server computer and find the difference between the PC browser request and the mobile request.

Comment: @ RaB I M using the emulator to test the application so its on the same network and still having the same problemmmm

Comment: You can also just try the same URL on the builtin browser and see if you get a 404 there too. Otherwise the only remaining option is to run wireshark and inspect the packets.